# How to allow S3 bucket cross account access using bucket policy

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-modules

Iam using the below bucket policy for various accounts to push logs in a centralized S3 bucket located in "ACCOUNT-ID-0" :

I have this policy in ACCOUNT-ID-0

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AWSLogDeliveryWrite",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com",
                    "config.amazonaws.com",
                    "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/vpc-flow-logs/AWSLogs/{ACCOUNT-ID-01}/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/cloudtrail/AWSLogs/{ACCOUNT-ID-02}/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AWSLogDeliveryAclCheck",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com",
                    "config.amazonaws.com",
                    "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the file located in "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/awsconfigconforms-rules/abc.yaml"

Iam trying to deploy a conformance pack using the template file abc.yaml.
Iam running the aws cli command from ACCOUNT-ID-03 and iam getting this error:
**An error occurred (InsufficientPermissionsException) when calling the PutOrganizationConformancePack operation: Insufficient read permissions on S3 URI**

Can someone help me with the bucket policy here?

Comment: So you want to allow read access to bucket in `ACCOUNT-ID-0` from `ACCOUNT-ID-03`?

Comment: Yes and that too for a specific folder in s3 : BUCKET-NAME/awsconfigconforms-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your current bucket policy in `ACCOUNT-ID-0` by the following statement:

```
{
    "Sid": "AllowReadsFromOtherAccount",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "ACCOUNT-ID-03"
    },
    "Action": "s3:GetObject",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/awsconfigconforms-rules/*"
}
```

Please note, that your IAM user/role which you use in the `ACCOUNT-ID-03` needs also permissions to read the s3.